# Kentico - Display query string as value of input field

Tags: kentico

I want to display the query string (if it's not empty) as the value of an input field, something like this `<input name="campaign" type="hidden" value="ABC Campaign {% if (QueryString.GetValue("utm_source") != null) { return "| QueryString.GetValue("utm_source")"} %}" />`

but couldn't make it work due to all the double quotes. I've tried escaping the quotes with back slash but didn't work. Could you help?
(The above code is placed inside the **Form > Layout**)

Comment: I'd suggest ensuring your querystring input is sanitized as well.  Placing it as a value in a hidden field isn't a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote to wrap entire statement and remove quotes for return statement:

```
value='ABC Campaign {% if (QueryString.GetValue("utm_source") != null) { return  QueryString.GetValue("utm_source")} %}'
```

Answer (score 0):

{%String.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString["utm_source"])?QueryString["utm_source"]:""%}

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use another syntax to get query parameters:

```
{% !String.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString.utm_source)?QueryString.utm_source:"" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter!

```
{% Convert.ToString(QueryString.utm_source, "") %}
```

But if you want it to have a | before it, then you'll have to use

{% string.isnullorwhitespace(QueryString.utm_source) ? "" : "|"+QueryString.utm_source %}